# Hide File Edit Insert from TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I just want to remove File Edit Insert View options from the menu in TinyMCE Editor.[image]

I try using inspect element and using below javascript code to delete the menu row:

```
document.getElementById('tinymce-16').style.display = 'none';
```

but it doesnt work. I get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple. You need to specify what you want displayed on initialization of the editor.

HTML

```
<form>
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

JS

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: [
        "code table"
    ],
    menubar: "format table tools",
});
```

This will only display format, table and tools. See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/t3wvze1m/)